# Zend Valid Post Values

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, http-post

Well  I created a simple form in html in the action I called the controller in this part works perfectly the values are catched , but I want validate this params when is null but not works , I don't use zendform because don't like me the style, and the method "isValid" is only work when I created a new form but in this case not works obviously

here is the code :

```
<HTML>
    <form action ="/insert" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="myname"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
        <input type ="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
<HTML>
```

PHP code

```
public function insertAction(){
     $form=$this->_getAllParams();

      if(!empty($form)){
         echo '</br> your name : '.$form['myname'] ;
         echo '</br> your last name : '.$form['lastname'] ; 
         exit;
      }
      else{
          echo 'Oops! What are you doing?!';
          exit;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function insertAction(){
    $form = new Your_Form ();
    if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
        // success!
        $values = $form->getValues();
        print_r($values); // should have your values
    } else {
    // failure!
    }
}
```

Your form is not just a bunch of params, is a class that helps you render and validate a form. Once you check the the values that were sent back are valid for your form then you can extract them using getValues() function. You dont need to render or create the form HTML manually. In the view you just render the form that you created in the controller and sent to the view :

```
echo $this->form;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I made this way previously, but the reason use this way in my form is because use input file and the method "input file" of Zend is some complex and I want change the style from view too. Greetings from Mexico

Comment: well the render part does not matter so much, you can generate the html in the way you want. But on the checking of the values, you should define and use a Zend_Form object, otherwise what is the point of using ZF at all... You can just do $this->getRequest()->getPost() and validate the params one by one

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the Zend_Form, you can not use the isValid method.
The quickest solution to this is to get your post and then validate your fields one by one.

Like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($request->isPost())
{
    $post = $request->getPost();
    $myname = $post['myname'];
    $lastname = $post['lastname'];

    if (!is_null($myname) && !is_null($lastname))
    {
        // do your actions here
    }else
    {
        // do your else actions here
    }
}
```